# Objects and Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, object, initialization

How to create an array of the objects and add object suach as this:

```
Student* student11 = new Student("Vince", "Vaughn", "7-th Avenue", "New York", "783-945-90-28", 49);
    Student* student12 = new Student("Vince", "Mcmahon", "Beverly Hills", "Los Angeles", "874-940-42-12", 47);
    Student* student13 = new Student("Stone Cold", "Steve Austin", "Dallas", "Texas", "385-421-47-95", 34);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you mean the following

```
Student *student = new Student[3] 
{
    { "Vince", "Vaughn", "7-th Avenue", "New York", "783-945-90-28", 49 },
    { "Vince", "Mcmahon", "Beverly Hills", "Los Angeles", "874-940-42-12", 47 },
    { "Stone Cold", "Steve Austin", "Dallas", "Texas", "385-421-47-95", 34 }
};
```

There can arise a problem if the class `Student` does not have the default constructor and you need to reallocate the array.

So pay attention to that instead of allocating the array "manually" you could use the standard template class `std::vector<Student>`.

Comment: Yep, that's the alternative approach, but if you need `student4` your stuck with a manual `realloc` as well `:)`